# circle image add in DiagonalLayout

Tags: java, android

I've created a layout with DiagonalLayout and I want add a circle image like the following picture shows.

[image: Like this image]

My layout code :

```
<com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
                android:background="@color/grey_alt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:diagonal_angle="10" app:diagonal_position="bottom" app:diagonal_direction="right">
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgBanner"
                    android:background="@color/grey_bg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
            </com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout>
```

and this is the demo image of my layout code

[image: this image]

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button

Answer (score 1):

try `layout_alignEnd` & `layout_alignTop`
hope this helps you....

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/diagonal_layout"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/diagonal_layout"
        android:layout_marginEnd= as per ur requirement 
        android:layout_marginTop= as per ur requirement />
```